# Cannot automate text entry through uiakeyboard in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, ui-automation

I am using UIAutomation to automate my iPhone app. But I am facing problem to enter text through keyboard in ios7. I am using this code:

```
 UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("s");
```

I have also tried :

```
 UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().windows()[4].keyboard().typeString("s");
 UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().keyboard().keys()["s"].tap();
```

but nothing works.The error I am getting is "UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().keyboard().keys()["s"] could not be tapped". Same error am getting for whatever I try.

But same code works fine in ios6. I am stuck very badly in this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.